# Salesforce Upsert using External Id gives an INVALID_FIELD Error

Tags: java, salesforce

I have a custom object `obj__c` with external id `extId__c` in SFDC. Based on the article in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm I do a `/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/obj__c/extId__c/45754?_HttpMethod=PATCH` call on Workbench. It updates the the record, if an `obj__c` with `extId 45754` already exists. But if the `obj__c` doesn't exist then the following error is thrown (Basically Insertion).

`message: The extId__c field should not be specified in the sobject data.
errorCode: INVALID_FIELD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. I was passing extId__c field in the payload body also, which is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

there are some changes post API version 37.0, which suggest using POST for insert instead of PATCH. You may try changing version to v36.0(or anything less than 37) , example: /services/data/v36.0/sobjects/obj__c/extId__c/45754?_HttpMethod=PATCH